# CRM Explorer does not show plug-in assemblies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, dynamics-crm-online

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Microsoft Dynamics 365 Developer Toolkit and 365 SDK.

Everithing was fine developing plug-ins but since last week CRM explorer does not show plug-in assemblies.
There are no errors, I connect CRM explorer to my organization, select a solution and it loads.
I can see entities and the rest of things but when I click on Plug-in Assemblies to expand it, It keeps loading for a few seconds and nothing appears.

Does anyone know what happens to my CRM Explorer?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try restart VS ?

Comment: Check if someone removed plugin assemblies from CRM solution which you use to connect in CRM explorer? Or Any changes in Tool paths?

Comment: I don't recommend using the Developer Toolkit plugin for VS, but I'd submit a support ticket with MS.

Comment: I've checked Tool paths and plugin assemblies in the solution I use to connect and they're both ok.
No matter which solution I choose, plugin assemblies never appears.

Comment: How can I restart VS???

Comment: @Daryl do you have a blog or anything about your issues with the Developer Toolkit? I've had some problems with it in the past, but I've had problems convincing others

Comment: @jasonscript 3 main issues. 1: it forces you to structure your solution in a very specific manner which I'm not a fan of (Don't believe you can just deploy 1 plugin, must deploy them all if you have multiple plugin projects in a single solution), 2: It is totally dependent on Visual Studio and is not properly updated.  Their isn't an officially support VS 2017 version of it.  3.  You have to install the plugin before you can even open up their custom project type.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this too. I had a plugin project with ILMerge, and the CRM explorer wouldn't load plugins, if Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk was not merged into the plugin dll. Even though it's not required when deploying to online.

Update: I found out that if you copy just the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll in the build folder with the plugin dll, CRM explorer will load plugins just fine. So no need to merge it.